# How $\boldsymbol{A}-\lambda\boldsymbol{I}$ singularity is connected to the innate properties of the system under investigation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, numerical-linear-algebra

From Charles George Broyden. Basic Matrices. The Macmillan Press Ltd, 1975.:

> We have already seen, in chapter 2, that if **A** is square and nonsingular a unique solution of the equation **Ax** = **b** exists for any arbitrary **b**. Equations of this form arise frequently when analysing the static behaviour of physical and economics systems and often represent the response of the system to the particular set of applied stimuli embodied in the vector **b**. If, however, we wish to investigate the dynamic behaviour of such systems we are led to the determination of those values of the scalar $\lambda$ for which **A** - $\lambda$**I** is singular. These values of **A** are associated with the innate properties of the system under investigation, for example, the natural frequencies of vibration of mechanical or electrical systems or certain variances obtained in statistical analyses, and as such are independent of applied stimuli. This is in marked contrast to the solution of the related set of linear equations **Ax** = **b**.

So I kind of get the static part. But how do we arrive at the conclusion that for the dynamic properties of the system we need to investigate the scalars $\lambda$ for which **A** - $\lambda$**I** is singular!? Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to read a bit more to get the full answer. The scalars $\lambda$ are the "eigenvalues" of $A$. In dynamics problems, you often have a linear differential equation $\dot{x}=Ax$, and the form of the solutions of this equation depend on the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear dynamical system may be described by a differential system of equations like this:

$$\frac{d\vec x}{dt}=\dot {\vec x}=A\vec x$$

To find the solution we are interested in those values for which a vector $\vec x$ is tranformed by A in a vector multiple of $\vec x$:

$$A\vec x=\lambda \vec x\implies (A-\lambda I)\vec x=0$$

The latter system has no trivial solutions if and only if $det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

The values $\lambda_i$ which satisfy the condition are the **eigenvalues** of A, corresponding vectors $\vec x_i$ are the **eigenvectors**.

Once you know an eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector you can indeed find a solution for the system:

> $$\frac{d\vec x}{dt}=\dot {\vec x}=A\vec v_i=\lambda_i\vec v_i\implies \vec x(t)=\vec v_ie^{\lambda_it}$$

Comment: Could you please point me to a basic example? I know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors but I have problem connecting the theory to the real world. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look here for example http://www.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/math221/DynSys.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I will check it!

Answer (score 0):

$A-\lambda I$ is singular iff $det(A-\lambda I)=0$, which means that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

If the system is linear, then you can easily determine its behaviour using these eigenvalues.

If the system is non-linear, then you can approximate its behaviour in a small neighbourhood.